# Pass interface object without declaring a struct

Tags: go, revel

How can I pass an `Interface{}` object without declaring a Struct? 
for example when I'm using the Revel framework I want to return an error on a specific case.

1. The following example is not working, I tried various conventions nothing worked, whats the right approach?

   return c.RenderJson(interface{"error":"xyz"})
2. Whats the right approach to return an error to the Client if i'm building a Server with the Revel framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 1. Try the following:

```
return c.RenderJson(map[string]string{"error": "xyz"})
```

`RenderJson` takes an interface, which means you can pass it anything.  You don't need to explicitly cast to an interface, though that would be done like

```
interface{}(map[string]string{"error": "xyz"})
```

For 2.  I am not certain, but I tend to have a helper function that takes the error string (or error type) and a status code and does the handling for me.

```
return HandleError(c, "xyz is not valid", 400)
```

And then `HandleError` just creates and writes the error.

If you are going to be handling errors in general, I don't know why you wouldn't make an error type though,

```
type RequestError struct {
    Error string `json:"error_message"`,
    StatusCode int `json:"status_code"`,
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. could you redirect me to a source that's saying what exactly does the `json:"error_message"` mean in the struct? I am a newbie to Golang so it's the first time i'm seeing it

Comment: Have a look in here: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal.  They are called struct tags.  This is how they are used via reflect: http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag.  And here is a bit of explanation in general: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to declare a named `struct` type prior, you could simply use:

```
return c.RenderJson(struct{ Error string }{"xyz"})
```